# serialize is causing a mess when it comes to gather information?

Tags: php, ajax

since I am learning on how to use serialize, I am facing a hiccup where after I used the below code which is the Jquery post

```
jQuery.post("d_in.php",jQuery("#myform").serialize(), function(data){
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
```

and let's say I have 2 inputs which names are Small$item_id, where each input name follows the items itself,

whenever I try

`echo $_POST['Small'.$item_id]` I get both in one

let's say 1 for small102-s and 3 for small1055-a

when I print the result I get as follows : 13

even when it comes to more items

how can I split the number?

Update #1:

i tried using `explode("&", $_POST['Small'.$item_id]` i am getting null, it seems the data is sent without the `&` it is sent together without any split.

Update#2:
here is whats in `d_in.php`

```
foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item)
        {
        $item_id    = $item['id'];
        $item_name  = $item['name'];
        $item_price = $item['price'];
        $item_qty   = $item['qty'];
        $item_ids = explode("-",$item_id);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($item_ids); $i++){

                                                $item_idn = join("",$item_ids);

                                                }



echo $_POST['Small'.$item_idn];
$item_idn = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me

```
<form id="test" method="post">
<input type="text" name="small102-s" id="small102-s" />
<input type="text" name="small1055-a" id="small1055-a" />
<input id="testbtn"  type="button" />
</form>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#testbtn").click(function()
{
var dataval=$("#test").serialize();
alert(dataval);
    $.post("1.php",dataval, function(data)
    {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
     });
 });
```

});

On the 1.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['small102-s'];
?>
```

Check Live **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/M6c2z/)**

Comment: i have updated the question please see what i used in d_in.php and btw when it comes to gather the information i am using a foreach loop that gets me the ids of the items which are in the cart allowing me to get everything what i am sending through ajax